# JQuery Autocomplete/ASP.NET Webhandler to include value of another textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

so I have been at this for quite a while (over a week) searching google and stackoverflow and all that. Can't seem to get a compilation of information to make this work.

[ASPX PAGE]

```
    <span>Make</span> <asp:TextBox ID="Make_SearchBox" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter Make"></asp:TextBox>
    <span>Model</span> <asp:TextBox ID="Model_SearchBox" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter Model"></asp:TextBox>
```

[JavaScript]

```
    <%--Autocomplete Function--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PageContent_Make_SearchBox").autocomplete("/WebHandlers/AutoComplete.ashx",{
            extraParams: { field: "Make" },
            autoFill: false
        });

        $("#PageContent_Model_SearchBox").autocomplete("/WebHandlers/AutoComplete.ashx", {
            extraParams: { field: "Model" },
            autoFill: false
        });
    });
  </script>
```

[ASHX WEBHANDLER - C#]

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // INITIALIZING NEEDED VARS
        string query = "";
        string sql = "";

        // CHECK "field" QUERY AND PASS TO SWITCH
        string field = context.Request.QueryString["field"];
        if (field != null)
        {
            switch (field)
            {
                case "Make":
                    query = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
                    sql = "Select DISTINCT Make from Vehicle Where Make LIKE '%" + query + "%'";
                    break;

                case "Model":
                    query = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
                    sql = "Select DISTINCT Model from Vehicle Where Model LIKE '%" + query + "%' AND Make LIKE (((MAKE TEXTBOX VALUE)));
                    break;
            }
        }

        string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        // CONNECT TO DATABASE, RUN QUERY AND RETURN DATA
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    context.Response.Write(reader.GetString(0) + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above works absolutely fine with the **make** text field. When I type "toy" in **make** field It passes like this:

```
GET http://localhost:26724/WebHandlers/AutoComplete.ashx?q=toy&field=Make
```

***What I want*** to do is after the user gets the **make** and starts writing in the **model** field it should search only the models pertaining to that make. The C# side of is is easy I suppose, just SQL query, but how do I get the JQuery to take the value of the **make** text field and add it to the query string.
Note that it needs to grab the value of the **make** text box only after it is full not at $document.ready.

Thank you all in advance. I will be sure to select a best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Autocomplete widget has a [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) that fires when the user selects an item. You can use this to filter the second autocomplete source based on what the user selected in the first one.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/B5fWc/8/ ...

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags, 
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#books").autocomplete({
                source: filter(availableBooks, ui.item.value)
            });
        }
    });
```

Are you using an older version of autocomplete? I don't think extraParams exists in the current version.

I'm not following exactly how you're getting the `q=toy` part, but I think an approach like this could do what you want.

```
$("#PageContent_Make_SearchBox").autocomplete({
    source: "/WebHandlers/AutoComplete.ashx?field=Make",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#PageContent_Model_SearchBox").autocomplete({
            source: "/WebHandlers/AutoComplete.ashx?field=Model&Make=" + ui.item.value
        });
    }
});
```

Then on the C# side you'd need to get the value they chose for Make from the "Make" query string param.

Comment: Thanks man. I am trying your method. Requires upgrading JQuery so I'll let you know what happens.